# "of" vs " from"

Tags: prepositions

Can we say:

> Little children are afraid from dark.

instead of:

> Little children are afraid of dark.

I have searched and found that whenever "fear" is there we use "of" but why is it so? Why we can not use first one? The meaning seems to be the same.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://www.thoughtco.com/difference-between-of-and-from-1211096) might help? All I can say is, every language has its nuances :D. (Though I would agree with you if you think English has more than most languages :D.)

Answer (score 3):

The object of **afraid of** would refer to that which is feared.

**afraid from** would refer to the origin or cause of the fear.

> She is afraid of fire.
>
> She won't go near the fire. She is afraid from having burnt her hands as a small child.